# store content of a tag in a string with elementtree in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and elementtree to copy the content of a tag in an XML file.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.003.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
         <MsgId>nBblsUR-uH..6jmGgZNHLQAAAXgXN1Lu</MsgId>
         <CreDtTm>2016-11-10T12:00:00.000+01:00</CreDtTm> 
         <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
         <CtrlSum>6</CtrlSum>
         <InitgPty>
            <Nm>TC 03000 Kunde 55 Protokollr ckf hrung</Nm>
         </InitgPty>
      </GrpHdr>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I want to copy the content of the 'MsgId' tag and save it as a string.
I've manage to do this with minidom before, but due to new circumstances, I have to settle with elementtree for now.
This is that code with minidom:

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse('H:\\app_python/in_spsh/{}'.format(filename_string)) 
message = dom.getElementsByTagName('MsgId')
for MsgId in message:
   print(MsgId.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Now I want to do the exact same thing with elementtree. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text value of a single element, you can use the [`findtext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.findtext) method. The namespace needs to be taken into account.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")   # Your XML document
msgid = tree.findtext('.//{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.003.03}MsgId')
```

With [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) and later, it is possible to use a wildcard for the namespace:

```py
msgid = tree.findtext('.//{*}MsgId')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your and a similar solution but both output 'None' when printed.

Comment: This may was silly by me but the original XML is not properly formatted so I deleted some of the tags. I will correct it in the question.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. It was a stupid typo that caused the issue. Thank you for your help, again!